# Sending Link Headers for Early Hints in PHP

Tags: php, http-headers, cloudflare

Cloudflare has introduced [Early Hints](https://blog.cloudflare.com/early-hints/) based on [Link Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link). I am a little bit confused about how I should send the link header in my PHP script.

As I understand, I should send the Link Header for the links to preconnect

```
Link: <https://example.com/style.css>; rel="preconnect"
```

I think we can send `HTTP 103 Early Hint` via PHP `headers`

```
header("Link: <https://example.com/style.css>; rel=preload; as=style", false);
```

Is it enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you actually are required to put nopush at the end, otherwise you're doing a Push, or set the status code header.

```
header("Link: <https://example.com/style.css>; rel=preload; as=style; nopush", false);
```

This would work.